# Enabling text compression for Service Fabric Services

Tags: azure, compression, azure-service-fabric

Recently, I was doing some research on how to implement compression for our Cloud Services (which are being hosted on IIS). I found some great resources on the MSFT documentation, namely, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpcompression/#overview) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/iis-compression/iis-compression-overview), that allowed me to get up and running fairly quickly.

For naive and manual testing, I'd simply change the `ApplicationHost.config` file and be on my way. Later on, I incorporated the same changes in code and this also worked.

Now, moving over to Service Fabric Services, and because our apps are no longer being hosted on IIS, I struggle to find a solution that can work similar to the ones above. I have found some articles detailing enabling compression per endpoint, but I'd rather do it for the entirety of the service.

Anyone have tips on how to enable text based compression on a Service Fabric Service? For context, this is to resolve an issue reported by the Dev Tools Lighthouse auditing plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure response [compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-2.2) using middleware '[Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression/)'.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddResponseCompression();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseResponseCompression();
    }
}
```

`app.UseResponseCompression` must be called before `app.UseMvc`.
Have clients set the `Accept-Encoding` request header.